# Monitor suddenly went to sleep and I can't wake it up

Tags: display, sleep, gpu, blank-screen

I think that's GPU problem: I was playing game and then screen turned black and said 'going to sleep mode'. And I can't wake it up. I've tried restart PC (it works), change monitor cable port, removing and installing back GPU. GPU seems work (fans spining). Can anyone help me plz?
My GPU: nVidia gtx 960

EDIT: I returned graphics card to seller, they are going to fix it, and borrow me another gpu but pc still doesn't work. If not gpu then what could cause my problem?

Comment: Does sound like a dead graphics card - can you test the monitor on any other device?

Comment: Monitor works on my laptop. So it means my graphics card really dead?

Comment: Have you overclocked the card? I had a similar issue with my card a while back where the overclock stopped the GPU form working, even in the BIOS. After I managed to turn it off (With another GPU) I was fine.

Comment: Nope, I haven't overclocked

Comment: You aren't getting an output from the GPU - do you have another graphics card or on board to test the computer with? If you can't even see as far as this BIOS screen, this usually means your card has failed.

Comment: Does 'failed' means it can't be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies on the Motherboard Suspend Modes. (ACPI: s1, s2 etc...)

Do a quick Google Search for both of the items bellow to get some understanding:
ACPI / s1 / s2 / s3 / Suspension Modes

Now you should go to your BIOS and make sure ACPI is enabled and as well any Suspension Modes Available. (S1, s2 etc,,.)

If your motherboard supports it, it will wake the machine correctly.
Else: Fails as you described.

Best regards;

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I've already founded solution: my PSU was broken. I repalced it and PC working.